# NSCollectionView maxes out at 2796202 items

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I created a simple Mac OSX app in XCode that tries to display a collection view (flow layout) with 10 million items. But, it seems to max out at 2796202 and I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: 10 million items?! Suppose `NSCollectionView` objects are only 100 bytes each. You're looking at 1 GB of memory. Could you find out the exact size for me? Run: `print(sizeof(NSCollectionView))`.

Comment: when I run `print(sizeof(NSCollectionView))`, it prints `8`. Before and after the collection view loads.

Comment: Hmmm that technique won't work for Class types like `NSCollectionView`